# import pandas : ImportError: cannot import name Counter in python 2.6.6

Tags: python, python-2.6

I am using python 2.6.6

I installed pandas as follows

```
pip install pandas
```

I got the following success message as well

```
Building wheels for collected packages: pandas
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pandas ... done
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/81/18/d5/9f087d2b2763f0573195c75f297cac96125d02dbb5aef2297b
Successfully built pandas
Installing collected packages: six, python-dateutil, pytz, pandas
Successfully installed pandas-0.19.1 python-dateutil-2.6.0 pytz-2016.10 six-1.10.0
```

However now when am importing it

```
import pandas as pd
```

It gives me the following error

```
>>> import pandas as pd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pandas.compat.numpy import *
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py", line 333, in <module>
    from collections import OrderedDict, Counter
ImportError: cannot import name Counter
```

What is missing here?

**Edit:**
I installed backport_collections 0.1 and tried again. It still gives error

Comment: You could install Anaconda for your OS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try installing Pandas from this package

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pandas/0.16.2/

Answer (score 2):

The pandas library uses the `collections.Counter` object which was introduced in Python 2.7; there's nothing to import in 2.6.

I think the easiest way around this is an upgrade to Python 2.7

Comment: I am not using counter at all.. I simply want to use pandas

Comment: `pandas` needs `Counter`

Comment: what is my alternative? how can make pandas work with 2.6

Comment: You can install an older version of pandas (`pip install pandas==0.15.2`), but then you can't ask pandas for too much since you're likely to miss out on some features

Comment: issue got resolved by using this version - 0.16.2, m only afraid now how much pandas got to offer with this. Any idea of the features which might be missing (apologies if am asking too much)

Comment: @Hardik Not sure about the changes.